# Aplicar efeito jQuery ao elemento HTML atual?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho o seguinte código que quando coloco para rodar, ele dá display:none e display:block em todos os elementos e eu gostaria que aplicasse este efeito só no elemento corrente:

```
//jQuery  
$( ".titulo" ).mouseover (
      function() {
        $(".overlayContent").css("display", "none");
      }
    );
    $( ".titulo" ).mouseout (
      function() {
        $(".overlayContent").css("display", "block");
      }
    );

//HTML
<article>
     <span class="overlayContent" style="display: block;"></span>
     <h2 class="titulo" style="padding: 0 75px">Post</h2>
</article>
```

Este span é um `background-color:#000` com `opacity:.5` que desaparece quando mouseover. Só que todos desaparecem e eu queria que só o corrente desaparecesse. Poderá ver o efeito neste link http://catalogos.axitech.com.br/

Comment: @Kazzkiq na verdade não existe funcionamento porque a unica coisa que aparece é o `overlay 0.5` entre a imagem e o titulo posicionado por `position:absolute` e `z-index` respectivos. Se inspecionar elemento verá exatamente a posição dos elementos.

Comment: E você quer que o overlay suma apenas quando se passar o código no título? Ou pode ser no bloco inteiro? Pode ser apenas com CSS ou você quer a solução com JavaScript?

Comment: @Kazzkiq pode ser no bloco inteiro. Eu tentei no bloco inteiro mas ficou piscando que nem discoteca ai eu comecei a tentar com o titulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que para este problema apenas CSS já resolva tudo:

```
.detalhesArticleHome .overlayContent{
    opacity:0.5;
}

.detalhesArticleHome:hover .overlayContent{
    opacity:0;
}
```

O que o código acima faz é atribuir a opacidade que você deseja ao elemento `.overlayContent` toda vez que o mouse passar pelo bloco inteiro.

Caso você queira fazer um efeito "fade-in" e "fade-out" no overlay, é possível utilizar ainda a propriedade `transition` do CSS para a animação.

Comment: Eu gostaria da aplicar um efeito mais trabalhado tipo fadein e fadeout uma vez com o script pronto.

Comment: Apliquei o efeito com transition e css mas isso só funciona a partir da versão 10 do Internet Explorer mas mesmo assim resolveu.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$( ".titulo" ).mouseover (
  function() {
    $(this).prev(".overlayContent").css("display", "none");
  }
);
$( ".titulo" ).mouseout (
  function() {
    $(this).prev(".overlayContent").css("display", "block");
  }
);
```

Comment: dsantoro se reparar no código no link <http://puu.sh/biOQY/307c5803e1.png> poderá verificar que o seu código não deu certo só porque a `class="overlayContent"` não está exatamente um item anterior a `class="titulo"` ... alguma ideia?

Comment: @dsantoro: Seria possével elaborar um pouco melhor sua resosta